# How much English is spoken at Japan Expo (Paris)

Tags: conventions, europe

I'm thinking of going to Japan Expo this year - as it is the largest convention in Europe, but because it is located in France, I'm unsure if I would enjoy it as much as my French - while passable - probably wouldn't get me through more complex conversations than ordering food, asking for directions, etc.

The convention's website does have an English version ([Here](http://www.japan-expo-paris.com/en/))  but I have been unable to find any information as to how much of the convention is bilingual (there would be no point in going to some guest talks for example)

Does anyone have experience of Japan Expo who could tell me how much English is spoken throughout the convention?

Comment: Senpai, are you in the right SE site? Shouldn't this be posted to travel.SE instead?

Comment: I think so, we have a conventions tag, and I'd say it'd be too localized for travel.SE

Comment: Acknowledged...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Been numerous times to this convention (as a pro and as a visitor).

Most of the publisher booths are from French publishers. Panels, activities are in French and speakers are in French. Some panels don't really require to understand French though (cosplay).

Some video projections are in English but it is rare.

Most of the booths will speak English, but it will mostly be approximate English.

Documentations (map and planning) and information booths are available in English.

The professional part (license market) is in English, but I don't think you will attend as a pro.

Comment: I went to this years one, and it was very much in French - but there was enough signage and events that didn't need the language to keep me happy :) For the bigger events like ECG, they had english & french

Answer (score 6):

I have not attended previous meetings of this convention, but I can tell from my professional knowledge that:

1. It is the largest in all Europe.
2. Many of the guests come from Japan.
3. This convention is considered a professional meeting point in the world of manga/anime, and as far as I know from my colleagues who have attended, all the meetings are in English.

Therefore, I think I can state with relative certainty that a significant portion will be in English or bilingual.

The people at the booths will probably attend you in English and French.

However, you might not find many English manga on sale. As far as I know, the manga they sell, except for some imported material in Japanese, are mostly licensed in France and edited by the respective publishers.

Comment: "but I can tell about my professional knowledge of it", what do you mean by this? Do you work in the anime/manga business?

Comment: Yes, I work on manga/anime/japanese culture events preparation, and I have some knowledge of this. Some of the members of my group attend at Japan Expo (France) and the another one (I don't remember the name) at Japan for business contacts.

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to say from "Stands dare to bet..." to the end of your answer. Would you please edit it a bit?

Comment: I'm talking about languages used by booths. They probably talk you on English and French.